# How to format SQL datetime properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, datetime-format

I need to introduce my date and time in a SQL field of type `datetime`. Currently, the format of date is `mm/dd/yyyy` and my time format `hh:ii`. I tried to send this data as
`$datetime=$date.' '.$time`, but didn't work, whatever the input is, in  the db I always have `00-00-00 00:00:00:00`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Does PHP not allow you to pass the value *as* a date/time value, avoiding string formatting entirely? (That's what I'd do in Java or C#, for example.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 $date="01/01/2017";  // This is the format you mentioned
 $time="22:11";      // This is the format you mentioned
 $time=strtotime("$date $time"); //if strtotime() confuses mm with dd, use mktime()
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time);    // MySQL Format
?>
```

Comment: Okay, that seems legit. Thanks

Comment: Just doing this now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as yyyy-mm-dd hh:km. That will always be picked up correctly by the database. If you only have the date as a string you will need to convert it using eg strtotime or substr.

Answer (score 0):

The default format for mysql date time is YYYY-MM-DD HH:II::SS
So for inserting custom date format into mysql you need to specify the datatype for column as varchar

Alternatively you can store date according to default format for mysql into table and for display purpose you can customize the date format using DATE_FORMAT function of mysql

Comment: Well, the problem is that the input will come as mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii, and has to be passed into the database.
I've seen something like `SET DATEFORMAT`, but not really sure how to use it